# Gracenote Entourage Demo Application Crashing

Tags: gracenote

I have downloaded the demo app from the Gracenote Developer website but its crashing for me and gives `Exe_Bad_access` on below line in `ViewDidLoad` method of `GNViewController.m`.

```
self.sdkManager = [[GnSdkManager alloc] initWithLicense:LICENSE_INFO error:nil];
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Is this the demo application you're referring to? https://github.com/dsgracenote/GN_Entourage_Demo

Comment: I edited your question to remove the client ID, tag and license you'd posted, since it would let anyone use your account ;) You don't won't to post those things publicly.

Comment: No problem Rich  - yes the demo Application

Comment: Hi Rich,
Please let me know where my error might be. 

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify:
- Did you make any modifications to the sample app?
- What version of Xcode are you using?
- What version of iOS?
- Are you seeing the problem in the simulator or an actual device?

Comment: I am using xcode 5 and testing in iPhone 4S with iOS 7.0.3.

Comment: I tried again but same error, I dont think its from my side, please check. Thanks, Ron

Comment: Please help someone...

Comment: Hey Rich Adams, please help me - I am unable to continue - let me know some info which can help please.

Comment: Ron, please do not ask the same question is several different threads. This question is a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149973/gracenote-entourage-crashing