# Gracenote Entourage Crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, gracenote

I have downloaded the demo app from the Gracenote Developer website but its crashing for me and gives Exe_Bad_access on below line in ViewDidLoad method of GNViewController.m.

```
self.sdkManager = [[GnSdkManager alloc] initWithLicense:LICENSE_INFO error:nil];
```

What's going wrong?

This is the demo applicaiton I am referring to. I am using xcode 5 and testing in iPhone 4S with iOS 7.0.3.

Comment: Hi, you made no modifications to the sample? This is the sample you have extracted, set your client ids, built, run and that's it?
Is this happening in the emulator? The phone, both?

Comment: This is a duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005935/gracenote-entourage-demo-application-crashing

Comment: Thanks for your support, i will remove that other thread.

Comment: it is happening in device and I just sample extracted and set our client ids and run, I did no modification in the sample just changes to client ids and got error unknown domain.